# compare two tables then sort them in excel

Tags: excel, compare, row

I have two tables with the same data but in different rows, I want to sort them in front of each other. each duplicate row in front of its duplicate.
[attached photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O0vNL.png)

Comment: Do you mean so that they are in line (result: still 2 tables, same rows are in line) or below each other (result: 1 table)

Comment: Also, make an attempt and post some code/formulae, let us know what you've tried.

Comment: I want two tables be sorted in front of each other. each code in front of its equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

In a new worksheet, copy the code data from one table and append to that a copy of the code data from the other. Apply Remove Duplicates to that column and sort ascending.

Now use that sheet to look up ([VLOOKUP](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/VLOOKUP-function-0bbc8083-26fe-4963-8ab8-93a18ad188a1) `Description`, `Uom` and `Unit Price` from one of your tables into three separate columns (say 2,3,4) and lookup up same fields from the other of your tables into a further three columns (say 5,6,7).

Wrap both formulae in IFERROR(....,"") to reduce noise.

I take it any numbering will be applied independently in a new sheet (ie `No.` is not required to be copied to there).

Incidentally you have a lot of unconventional hyphens (eg `L-80` is never normally written other than as `L80`), `m` for OCTG as a unit of measure leads to many problems and with competent staff a structured catalogue could be advisable for a high value of stock and long-term storage.

Comment: I really didn't get where you gonna get with that explanation. it doesn't works for me. I need something like VBA code to be able to do that. because it is a huge list of information.